# Introduction to Localization of Topological Spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to learn [localization of topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_topological_space) but am not sure where to start. Can anyone recommend some introductory materials? It would be great if it contains detailed motivations, definitions, examples, applications, etc.

Comment: No matter what, if you ever read Bousfield-Kan's *Homotopy limits, completions and localizations*, start with part II.

Comment: I clicked on this question thinking, wow I can't believe someone is asking about this niche topic, one that I've collected quite a bit of literature on. However, from the comments and answer, it's clear that this question is not about localization in topology in the sense introduced by Kuratowski and studied by Vaidyanathaswamy, Hamlett, Jankovic, Hayashi, Njastad, Samuels, ... !

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I am not familiar with this; what is the localization in the sense introduced by Kuratowski?

Comment: Roughly speaking, it has to do with generalizing the notions "closure of a set" (thought of as all points at which the set is not locally empty) and "set of limit points of a set" (thought of as all points at which the set is not locally finite) by replacing the empty set/collection and the collection of finite subsets with an arbitrary ideal of sets (in the space), where an ideal is a collection of subsets of the space that is closed under finite unions and subsets. See [this](http://repository.ias.ac.in/59515/1/10-pub.pdf) [free] or [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324512) [JSTOR].

Comment: What typically happens is that a new topology is formed, and there are a lot of interesting results relating to how the new topology compares with the old topology in terms of properties (relative to the old topology) of the ideal. Some of the stuff is quite interesting, but in my opinion most of the interesting stuff was done by the early 1990s and (again, in my opinion) much of the recent work seems to be involved with highly technical epsilon-variations of previous work. But if you're interested, you can google "new topologies from old via ideals", probably the most cited paper in the area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a modern treatment, using model categories, in the first part of "Model Categories and their Localizations" by Hirschhorn. A more "classical" treatment can be found in "More Concise Algebraic Topology" by May and Ponto.
I hope this will be useful for your study!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation!!